# Is my kombucha scoby safe?

Tags: kombucha

My scoby has developed red flecks. There are only about 3 of them. Is it still ok?

The rest of the scoby is the normal whitish beige color.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, nothing short of a scoby being fuzzy, hairy, bright blue or green, smelling like a diaper pail or biting you is all ok! Mold is pretty much the only absolute no-no. If it isn't moldy and you are happy with the smell (should be slightly vinegary) just taste it. You'll know if it's ok or not by whether you spit it out or not :).

Comment: Thank you for this.  My first scoby got grey and fuzzy, and I was worried it went bad, but the 'booch didn't taste like gym socks, so I figured was alright.